# Dynamic class selection before object detection

Tags: python, django, object-detection

I have a set of predefined classes to be detected in my object detection code. I want to choose the classes dynamically before the detection starts. Is this possible?  *I am selecting only the classes that I have trained the model for*

I have to detect only the selected classes

Comment: welcome. show your attempt. [tour], [ask], [mre]